# Sideloading Office Add-In cant start because it isn't setup properly

Tags: office365, office-js

I have been following this [link](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing) to try and sideload my add-in for testing.  Considering it only requires the add-ins manifest to be uploaded, I figured there would be a series of file references within the manifest.  I bundles all the files into a single folder and changes the references within the manifest.

However, when I upload the manifest as suggested by the guide it loads as expected, but when trying to run it, it returns the error: 'Sorry, but we can't start this add-in because it isn't setup properly'.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by a series of file references, and what is it that you tried to bundle?

Comment: A manifest should be just the XML file, and you'll still need a web server of some sort (local IIS instance, or a Node-based server) to host the actual web files.